# What causes the degeneration of correlation in a simulated time series?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation, simulation

I am trying to simulate an ARMA(1,1) process with the following characteristics:

- $\phi$ = 0.97
- $\theta$ = 0.80
- Standard deviation $s$ = 245
- Mean $m$ = 1000

---

```
phi = 0.97
theta = 0.80
s = 245
m = 1000

set.seed(1000)
require(FitARMA)

test <- SimulateGaussianARMA(phi, theta, 20000,InnovationVariance = s^2,UseC=T) + m
```

When I calculate the mean and standard deviation of my simulated series I get

```
c(mean(serieteste),sd(serieteste))
#[1] 997.9931 297.6867 - which isn't bad at all
```

However, when  I calculate the ACF, I get values that aren't as high as $\phi$. I'm sure I'm missing something here, after all, the autoregressive coefficient isn't the same as correlation. But I did think I'd see a higher $\phi$ for my first correlation in the simulated series because, usually, for high values of both $\phi$ and $\theta$, the ACF will decrease slowly.

```
Acf(serieteste, lag.max = 2, plot = F)
    #0     1     2 
    #1.000 0.431 0.418
```

> What have I missed?

---

P.S.: I want to simulate a time series with a standard deviation of 300. The number I inserted as the standard deviation for the innovation came from a derivation that use both $\phi$ and $\theta$ to find the "noise's" standard deviation. That's why I said the mean and standard deviation aren't bad at all.

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible because you haven't defined the variable `fi`.  Is your problem perhaps an error in coding, then?

Comment: My bad. I'll fix it now. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: You should probably derive the expression for the ACF at lag 1 as a function of the parameters, it's not that simple. In particular, if $\phi=\theta$ (in the parametrization used by `FitARMA`, which isn't the same as the one used by `stats::arima` or `forecast::Arima`), then the AR and MA parts cancel and the ACF at lag 1 is zero, no matter how high $\phi$ and $\theta$ are.